# How to publish for top journals?

Tags: publications, research-process

I am a Software Engineer and I have finished BSc in Computer Science and Engineering, currently I am working as well as doing some researches related to Computer Science in my spare time. I am curious to know how I can publish for top journals as a  single contributor without any mentors or supervisors. I will highly appreciate if you provide any feed back or reference related to the process.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Writing well is one prerequisite -- e.g., start by fixing the many grammatical mistakes in your question!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions I highly appreciate it

Comment: Before you ask about publishing in top journals, why not ask about doing great research?

Comment: Thank you very much I will ask about it in a seperate question. Currently I am in the process of defining scope of the research work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple but difficult.

Write the best papers if you want to publish in the best journals.

There is no bar for being an individual. Do good work. Write it up properly and submit it.

But, to write good papers without any guidance is very difficult. There must be something "real" behind the papers, usually research and that, alone, is difficult. The first paper is the hardest. It gets easier after 10 papers, or so. But if you submit a lot of poor papers to top journals you might get a reputation as a crank. Having people to bounce ideas off of can be a big help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable guidance . I highly appreciate it.

Comment: 'good work' -- difficult to appreciate if you do not have a teacher who produces 'good work' him/herself.  Even harder if you do not have the skills to construct said 'good work'.   'Write it up properly' is also a hard one.  Again, you need a good teacher who can write well.

Comment: Reading many papers from top journals and some below that level consciously may help, and then asking yourself whether you understand why those in the top journals ended up there, and how your own work compares to this.